# How to use LiveData in Coroutine on Android

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

In my application I want use **Room** database into **MVVM** architecture and for this I used **LiveData** with **Couroutines**.
I write below codes and I want check data, if data is **empty** then show empty layout.
I write below codes, but after run application show me Error and application has crashed!
**Dao codes :**

```
@Dao
interface DataDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM $my_table ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getAllData(): LiveData<MutableList<DataEntity>>
}
```

**Repository codes:**

```
class MainRepository @Inject constructor(private val dao: DataDao) {

   fun allData() = dao.getAllData()
}
```

**ViewModel codes :**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val dataList = repository.allData()
    val isEmpty = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    fun checkData() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        if (repository.allData().value!!.isEmpty()) {
            isEmpty.postValue(true)
        } else {
            isEmpty.postValue(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Show me this error in **logcat** :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.myapp.viewmodel.MainViewModel$checkData$1.invokeSuspend(MainViewModel.kt:22)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@35a0def, Dispatchers.Main]
```

Show error for this line : `repository.allNotes().value!!.isEmpty()`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you don't need to launch a coroutine in `MainViewModel.checkData()` method, because there is no `suspend` functions invoked. And regarding the error, please check the value in `LiveData` on `null`:

```
fun checkData() {
    val data = repository.allData().value
    if (data == null || data.isEmpty()) {
        isEmpty.postValue(true)
    } else {
        isEmpty.postValue(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I used your code and fix my above error. but after change code always show me isEmpty is true! I changed database size is for example 5. but always run this line `isEmpty.postValue(true)` . I think this problem is for **data==null** . when delete this show me **nullPointer** error. why data is null ?

Comment: Can't tell for sure, maybe the sql request to Database is wrong.

Comment: What is the name of the table you a getting data from? Try to change the return type of  `getAllData` method from `LiveData< MutableList<DataEntity>>` to `LiveData<List<DataEntity>>` in `DataDao`: `fun getAllData(): LiveData<List<DataEntity>>`